# How can I add some custom field in odoo eCommerce website Shopping cart table

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view, odoo-website

I want to add custom fields like following image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit `website_sale.cart_lines`  in odoo 9 or `website_sale.cart` in odoo8 ,either use **position**  `replace` or `after`/`before` like `<xpath expr="//tbody" position="replace">`
 and  put your code in the `xpath`(update `tr` and `td`).

Comment: can you give me some example please...